# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am not getting response of api call using angular 4 service but same call working in browser i am facing below given error - Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

Comment: Is that coming in code? Or coming to you as an email?

Comment: It coming in browser console when we are running angular 4 project.

Comment: this is a common issue to deal with angular and apis, please [Read this post](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/)

Comment: The same question again code man! Post it!

Comment: You need to pass custom header with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` and also you need to configure your api server for the same. For more info please follow [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS](link)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699940/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb-blocked-cross-origin)

Comment: Add responseType as a member of your httpoptions with the value of 'test' as 'json' like this  ```const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
  responseType: 'text' as 'json'
};```

Comment: You will have to bind the response data to a class variable and parse the class variable if you would like the text data back as json. This is all just a temporary fix for now.

Answer (score -1):

I was having similar challenging in getting response as well. With mine, I was actually making an http get request with respect to Google OpenID Connect but maybe your use case might be different.

So this is how I fixed it. Upon sending an authentication request to Google, I used a wrong base URL though it was working alright in the browser. I changed the base url rather to `https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` in my Angular 8 service layer. Maybe you can check it out.

Hope it helps :)