# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin

Tags: angular

Error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://abcd.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I am getting the above error whenever I'm trying to make http post request from Angular 4. I'm sending Chinese characters in JSON body and already allowed

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Accept,x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,charset=utf-8");
```

Facing this issue whenever posting Chinese characters.

Comment: your question is not clear. What you are asking? Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Access-Control-Allow-Headers might be causing the issue - try Access-Control-Allow-Headers with value *

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` "solves" CORS issue not CORB